# Maven using azure CICD - How to secure my user credentials

Tags: maven, security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I am having my test case ready in local environment and ready to shift in azure CICD pipeline.

TO run the test case I need few settings including User credentials. Now when I move my code from local to clod I can't pass user credential because of security concern.

I read some article on Azure Key Vault to save secrets and then we can read it in pipeline.

But any one know **how can I pass/read Azure key vault secrets in Maven task of Azure Pipeline** so that I have don't have to save credentials in code itself.

Other solutions also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option would be use [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault). You may link variable group with Azure Key Vault:

[image]

And then when you [use this variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group) in pipeline you will get secrets available as variables.

So if you have secret `MyPassword` in Azure Key Vault and you will follow all above steps then in pipeline you may reffer to it as `$(MyPassword)`.

Another options is to use [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops)

In the simplest manner you can use secret variable:
[image]

Or secret variable in variable group:

[image]

In Maven task you can use variable like this `mavenPomFile: $(YourVariables)`:

```yaml
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: $(YourVariables)
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. But my question still same how can i utilize or pass in Maven task ?

Comment: Simply use $(MyPassword) like any other variables. You can find more details about variables here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: @V_B I edited my answer. Please check this if it helps you understand how you can use variables in Maven task.